# How can I get the color of the selection in TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am creating an application with a TinyMCE editor embedded inside it. I want the controls for my application to update when the selection inside the tinyMCE editor changes, so the font, size and color menus show the font, size and color of the selection. Font and color work fine, but I can't figure out how to get the color. Here is the code I am using:

```
myTinyMCESettings.handle_node_change_callback = function(editor_id,node,undo_index,undo_levels,visual_aid,any_selection){
    var editor = tinyMCE.get(editor_id);
    selectionChanged(editor,!any_selection);
};

tinyMCE.init(myTinyMCESettings);

function selectionChanged(ed,selection){    
    var fontName = ed.queryCommandValue('FontName');
    var size = parseInt(ed.queryCommandValue('FontSize'));
    var color = ed.queryCommandValue('ForeColor');
}
```

But `color === false`. How can I get the foreground color of the selected text or the text at the insertion point within tinyMCE?

**EDIT:** Tracking this down further, on line 12377 of `tiny_mce_prototype_src.js` I see:

```
// Registred commands
o = t.editorCommands.queryCommandValue(c);
```

When I walk through this in my debugger, `t.editorCommands.queryCommandValue(c);` returns false.

Comment: Do you want to get the color of the selection or the color chosen on the panel with instruments?

Comment: Do you want the background-color or text color?

Comment: @Cheery I want the color of the selected text; I am hiding the TinyMCE toolbar.

Comment: @Thariama I want the text color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try to do it in another way (did not check it) - taking computed style:

```
myTinyMCESettings.handle_node_change_callback = function(editor_id,node,undo_index,undo_levels,visual_aid,any_selection){
    var editor = tinyMCE.get(editor_id);
    var color =  tinyMCE.DOM.getStyle(node, 'color', true); // computes current color
    selectionChanged(editor,!any_selection);
};
```

Comment: Sorry, `Object tinyMCE has no method 'getStyle'`

Comment: @Josh           Sorry, missed one word :) Check the updated version. It computes current style instead of reading style from css or style attribute.

Comment: This *almost* works. Problem is, on HTML like `<p><span style="color: #87c001;"><strong>test</strong></span></p>` it returns `""`  I guess because the `<strong>` doesn't have a CSS color, the `<span>` does...

Comment: @Josh          And getStyle is supposed to get the color based on the color of the parent. Does it? If not, write it as tinyMCE.DOM.getStyle(node, 'color', true) ps: I'm sorry for so many updates.. I'm a fan of CKEditor :)

Answer (score 3):

I dont know if you solved this, but what i did was:

```
var node = ed.selection.getNode();
node_array = tinyMCE.DOM.getParents(node);
for(i = 0; i < node_array.length; i++){
    var the_node = node_array[i];
    var color = the_node.style.color;
    if(color != "" && color != "undefined" && color != null){
        return color;   
    }
}
return "";
```

Where ed is the variable of your tinyMCE editor.

Answer (score 1):

This will work if your selection is fully inside the colored text

```
tinymce.get('my_editor_id').selection.getNode().style.color;
```

Comment: So far this looks promising! Testing further now and will accept if it works!

Comment: This *almost* works. Problem is, on HTML like `<p><span style="color: #87c001;"><strong>test</strong></span></p>` it returns `""`  I guess because the `<strong>` doesn't have a CSS color, the `<span>` does...

Answer (score -1):

This will do

```
tinymce.get('my_editor_id').getContentAreaContainer().style.color= "red"
```